# How to properly handle errors for custom message?

Tags: angular, error-handling, nested, formgroups

I write a function that check the errors, and than i use `ngIf` to display (or not) a custom text. this way:

```
// ts
handleError = (controlName: string, errorName: string) => {
    return this.form.controls[controlName].hasError(errorName);
}

// html
<mat-error *ngIf="handleError('tipo', 'required')">Campo obbligatorio</mat-error>
```

It works nice for "one-level" form group. But what about nested form group? Such as:

```
this.form = this.fb.group({
    field1: [data.field1, [Validators.required]],
    myObj: this.fb.group({
        field2: [data.myObj.field2, [Validators.required]],
    })
});
```

Here it seems to crash (saying *Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'hasError')* on console).

What's so the best approch to iterate any nested formgroup and check for errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [get](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#get) method to retrive control, so that you can pass dot delimated value to access nested formcontrol.

**component.ts**

```
handleError = (controlName: string, errorName: string) => {
    return this.form.get(controlName).hasError(errorName);
}
```

**component.html**

```
<mat-error *ngIf="handleError('myObj.field2', 'required')">Campo obbligatorio</mat-error>
```

Comment: What if I'm within a FormArray? Which is discriminate by a index? Can't do myObj.item[x].field :(

Comment: You can access FormArray also ['formGroupKey', ArrayIndex,]==>handleError(['myObj',0], 'required') something like

Comment: You use dot delimated string or Array check documentation: 
https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#get

Comment: Tried your suggesion: `<mat-error *ngIf="handleError('ingredienti.[farine,itemIndex].quantita', 'required')">Campo obbligatorio</mat-error>` but it does error

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: it says "ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'hasError')"

Comment: Which means you might be passing wrong argument, can you create small stackbkitz>

Comment: I follow your suggestion. Here's the function:  `handleError = (controlName: string, errorName: string) => {
    return this.form.get(controlName).hasError(errorName);
  }`

Comment: I made a example please check:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-a1bxoa?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: I've added another level, as for "ingredienti", from your example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ffltbg?file=src/app/app.component.ts . it seems to give the same exact error...

Comment: When using array you should pass each level as individual string something like this console.log(this.handleError(['anotherLevel','arr', 0], 'required'));

Comment: Yes, but I'm within a component on html page. It is nested on another levels, so I need to pass the whole path; other wise how do I catch the element? refers to my prev code: `<mat-error *ngIf="handleError('anotherLevel.[farine,itemIndex].name', 'required')">Campo obbligatorio</mat-error>`

Comment: Can't  you pass each formgroup/control key something like ['anotherLevel','farine',itemIndex,'name']?

Comment: This way? `<mat-error *ngIf="handleError('[anotherLevel,farine,itemIndex.name]', 'required')">Campo obbligatorio</mat-error>`? I got the same error...

Comment: Acutally still you are passing string array, it should be array inside string or number handleError(['anotherLevel','farine',itemIndex.name]', 'required')"

Comment: Now, this way: handleError(['anotherLevel','farine',itemIndex,'quantita'], 'required')" it says "core.mjs:6485 ERROR Error Code: undefined
Message: Converting circular structure to JSON"

Comment: Please create stackblitz.

Comment: Not very good at stackblitz. Here's my attempt, with my code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-n1xuir?file=src/app/app.component.html (even if it does errors, not sure why, but not related to my code I believe?)

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-nm48u8?file=src/app/app.component.ts , I made some changes in html, it's working fine

Comment: I see. I think this is more related on the way I add new form item. As for this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71537428/whats-the-best-way-to-add-remove-dynamically-form-array-item . Maybe its the wrong way? I've accepted this answer as "Correct". Can you help the other question?

Comment: Sure. I will try my best.