# What's the best way to add/remove dynamically Form Array item?

Tags: angular, data-binding, formarray

Here's how I bind data received from an API to my Form Group/Array, on the CTOR:

```
  this.api.getRecipe(id).subscribe((data) => {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      nome: [data.nome, [Validators.required]],
      ingredienti: this.fb.group({
        acqua: [data.ingredienti.acqua, [Validators.required]],
        farine: this.fb.array(
          data.ingredienti.farine.map(item => (
            this.fb.group({
              quantita: [item.quantita, [Validators.required]],
              nome: [item.nome]
            })
          ))
        )
      })
    });
  });
```

And this is how I iterate `FormArray's farine` items on View:

```
  <mat-card *ngFor="let item of form.get('ingredienti').get('farine')['controls']; let itemIndex = index">
    <div [formGroupName]="itemIndex">
      <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput type="number" formControlName="quantita" />
      </mat-form-field>
      <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput type="text" formControlName="nome" />
      </mat-form-field>
    </div>
    <button type="button" (click)="addFarina()">Add</button>
  </mat-card>
```

Now, clicking on `addFarina()`, I'd like to simply add a new item on `FormArray's farine`.
I did this:

```
  addFarina() {
    let farineForm = this.form.value.ingredienti.farine;
    let farineFormControls = this.form.get('ingredienti').get('farine')['controls'];

    if (farineForm.length < 4) {
      const farina = this.fb.group({
        quantita: [null, [Validators.required]],
        nome: ['']
      })

      farineForm.push(farina);
      farineFormControls.push(farina);
    }
  }
```

But I feel like I'm not really using the potentially of this framework, updating manually both `this.form` items and related f`arine's controls`.

What's the best way to "edit" the data on form and subscribe edits also on View? So I don't need to manually manage the link between Data and View.

Comment: Acutally you no need  farineForm.push(farina) this code ,After adding formGroup to formArray you can read the value by farineFormControls.value

Comment: take a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53708499/dynamic-form-using-ngfor-and-submitting-values-from-it/53710438#53710438

Comment: @Chellappanவ that's not really true. If I don't do `farineForm.push(farina)`, than when I send data via API (i.e. `this.api.addRecipe(this.form.value).subscribe(...)`), the form's values are not updated/present. That's why I update both, updating both FormControls and form value...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should call [push](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray#push) method on formArray control. Since you are pushing new FormGroup inside normal array underlaying FormGroup is not get updated.

```
    addFarina() {
        let farineForm = this.form.value.ingredienti.farine;
        let farineFormControls = this.form.get('ingredienti').get('farine') as FormArray;
    
        if (farineForm.length < 4) {
          const farina = this.fb.group({
            quantita: [null, [Validators.required]],
            nome: ['']
          })
    
          farineFormControls.push(farina);
        }
        console.log(this.form.get('ingredienti').value);
      }
```

Now you should be able to access all formValue like this no need to push values inside array manually.

```
this.api.addRecipe(this.form.value).subscribe(...)
```

[**Working Stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ac87dk?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: it doesn't work on my side. if I farineFormControls.push(farina), this.form.value later is not updated

Comment: this line you need to change        let farineFormControls = this.form.get('ingredienti').get('farine')['controls'];
 ===>     let farineFormControls = this.form.get('ingredienti').get('farine') as FormArray;

Comment: you were right! works perfect now, thanks! is there a way to get the size of FormArray? so don't need let farineForm = this.form.value.ingredienti.farine; anymore...

Comment: I see SO didn't place Bounty to you automatically. Sorry. I've added to it right now :)